# #2: Create Your Own Animation from Java Script FOR KIDS JavaScript FOR KIDS doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript

I only started my way to JavaScript development. I'm trying to complete a task from the book for kids and I'm stuck in the following:[Task description is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kYiR.png)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Interactive programming</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="heading">Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        var leftOffset = 0;
        var topOffset = 0;
        var max = 200;
        var moveHeading = function () {
            var currentDirection;
            if (!currentDirection || currentDirection === topOffset) {
                for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                    $("#heading").offset({left: leftOffset});
                    leftOffset++;
                }
                currentDirection = leftOffset;
            }
            if (currentDirection === leftOffset) {
                for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                    $("#heading").offset({top: topOffset});
                    topOffset++;
                }
                currentDirection = topOffset;
            }
            if (currentDirection === topOffset) {
                for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                    $("#heading").offset({left: leftOffset});
                    leftOffset--;
                }
                currentDirection = leftOffset;
            }
            if (currentDirection === leftOffset) {
                for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                    $("#heading").offset({top: topOffset});
                    topOffset--;
                }
                currentDirection = topOffset;
            }
        };
        setInterval(moveHeading, 30);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that under debugging I do see how it moves from side to side in a form of square, but when I open the page in a browser tab(without opening DevTools), it doesn't move like it is requested in the Task. What am I missing here?

Comment: Hi there, the fact that it works with DevTools makes me feel is something related to caching. Have you tried to do a hard refresh on the browser (CTRL+F5) just in case?

Comment: Hi  I've just tried Ctrl+F5 and it didn't help. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make this way better. But for now :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1 id="heading">Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        var leftOffset = 0;
        var topOffset = 0;
        var max = 200;
        var counter = 0;
        var currentDirection = "right";
        var moveHeading = function() {
            if (currentDirection === "right") {
                $("#heading").offset({
                    left: leftOffset
                });
                leftOffset++;
                if (counter === max) {
                    currentDirection = "bottom";
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
            if (currentDirection === "bottom") {
                $("#heading").offset({
                    top: topOffset
                });
                topOffset++;
                if (counter === max) {
                    currentDirection = "left";
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
            if (currentDirection === "left") {
                $("#heading").offset({
                    left: leftOffset
                });
                leftOffset--;
                if (counter === max) {
                    currentDirection = "top";
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
            if (currentDirection === "top") {
                $("#heading").offset({
                    top: topOffset
                });
                topOffset--;
                if (counter === max) {
                    currentDirection = "right";
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
            counter++;
        };
        setInterval(moveHeading, 5);

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

but you can write this more compact and clean like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1 id="heading">Hello, world!</h1>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        let max = 200,
            counter = 0,
            x = [1, 0, -1, 0],
            y = [0, 1, 0, -1],
            idx = 0,
            el = $("#heading"),
            l = 0,
            t = 0,
            move = () => {
                l += x[idx];
                t += y[idx];
                el.offset({
                    left: l,
                    top: t
                });
            },
            moveHeading = () => {
                if (counter++ < max) {
                    move();
                    return;
                }
                idx++;
                if (idx > 3) idx = 0;
                counter = 0;
                moveHeading();
            };
        setInterval(moveHeading, 5);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```